# Django request threads and persistent database connections

Tags: django

I was reading about CONN_MAX_AGE settings and the documentation says:

> Since each thread maintains its own connection, your database must support at least as many simultaneous connections as you have worker threads.

So I wonder, On uWSGI, how does a Django process maintain it's own threads, does it spawn new thread for each request and kill it at the end of request?

If yes, how does a ceased thread maintain the connection?

Comment: it depends which application server are you using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django is not in control of any threads (well... maybe in development server, but it's pretty simple), but uWSGI is. uWSGI will spawn some threads, depending on it's configuration and in each thread it will run django request handling.

Spawning threads may be dynamic or static, it can be strictly 4 threads or dynamic from 2 to 12 depending on load.

And no, there is no new thread on each request because that will allow someone to kill your server by making many concurrent connections to it because it will spawn so many threads that no server will take it.

Requests are handled one by one on each thread, main uWSGI process will round-robin requests between threads. If there are more requests than threads, some of them will wait until others are finished

In uWSGI there are also workers - independent processes that can spawn own threads so load can be better spreaded.

Also you can have multiple uWSGI servers and tell your HTTP server (apache, proxy) to spread requests between them. That way you can even serve your uWSGI instances on different machines and it will all look like from the outside as one big server.

Comment: Hi is that right that uWSGI is reusing the threads? Do you have any documentation to support it? Cheers.